# Python Peewee - How to select and alias a literal column value?

Tags: python, peewee

Given the following model:

```
class User(BaseModel):
    name = TextField()
```

How do I execute the following sql:

```
SELECT name, 'hello' as foo
FROM user
```

I've found that I can use `peewee.Alias`, but I'm not sure if this is the ideal approach:

```
>>> print(User.select(User.name, Alias('hello', 'foo'))
SELECT "t1"."name", 'hello' AS "foo" FROM "users" AS "t1"
```

Is there an official way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example is not the correct way. Use `Value`:

```
User.select(User.name, Value('hello').alias('foo'))
```